# Send email with column values before and after change with workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow, column-data

I am trying to send an email to specified users when a column in a list changes in MOSS 2007 with workflow. I have a comments column in a list and whenever any user updates that comment, a mail should go to the creator and specific group stating what has changed.

I saw a response which states to create 2 lists and keep them in sync and compare values of comments from the two lists. But that is not a perfect solution.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event receiver instead and handle ItemEditing or ItemEdited event - it provides BeforeProperties and AfterProperties. And it's more natural to use an event receiver for such a short fully automatic task as email notification.

Comment: Here is a tutorial: http://aarebrot.net/blog/2010/08/creating-custom-list-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2007/

Answer (score 0):

In fields like Comments, you can enable a setting to "Append Changes To Existing Text". When you do this, notifications will show the changes.

Comment: Go it. But then is it possible to compare the two versions of the field and send a mail accordingly of the text that is changed.

Comment: Well, my point was that the notification does this of the box. I now realize that you want to do it in a workflow, so my reply doesn't answer your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: The problem with an alert is that it is at the list level and not the item level. Ashish likely has different people who want to know about only certain changes. For this you should use an event receiver as Alex Boev suggested.